# PHP separate acces to some links

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a table in DB where I put all the admins and their rights. I am setting theri rights with letters A-Z and each letter has access to something else. The thing is I want to check where they have access and show links only to those areas. For now I got an idea to put all those letters in some aray with for loop and then when rendering the menu output only those items where they have access with `if (in_array(letter, rights))` I think this would work but I would like to know whether there is another way

Comment: I wouldn't use letters, as it is difficult to maintain "hmmm giving access to user administration... was it `M` or `Q`?"

Comment: The idea of this was that I would have in administration option to add admins and there would be checkboxes with the letters as values.

Comment: This question might also be useful to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199252/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-permissions-for-a-web-application-bitmask-or-da

Comment: So I would end with 3 tables: admins, permitions, and admin_permitions. To the admin_permitions I would send admin_id and permition_id. Right?

Comment: Sorry to be the grammar nazi here, but 'permition' is actually "permission" - correct spelling will help any other developers dealing with your code

Comment: yea np and thanks :). But still. would it be the final solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a PHP class that I use in all my projects that require different access for different roles.  I put a copy of the class out on paste bin: [class_role_restrictions.php](http://pastebin.com/VubBkakb).

This class also requires another class I wrote, which can be obtained here: [better_mysqli.php](http://pastebin.com/ATyzLUfK)

The initial setup involves the creation of some database tables (The SQL create statements are found in comments at end of the class_role_restrictions.php file) and adding roles / user memberships via it's admin interface.

Detailed setup/usage can be obtained here: [role_restrictions_detailed_example.php](http://pastebin.com/apfnSK8S)

Once it is setup you can use it like this:

```
<?php

  include_once('class_role_restrictions.php');
  include_once('better_mysqli.php');


  $mysqli = new better_mysqli('your_server', 'your_user', 'your_pass', 'your_db_name');
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     error_log(sprintf("Can't connect to MySQL Server. Errorcode: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()));
     exit;
  }


  $role = new role_restrictions($mysqli, 'http://your_server.com/path/to/this/page/example.php');



  // == Restrict an entire page to authorized users only ==
    $role->restrict_to('role_name, to_restrict user_to', 'username_currently_logged_in');
  // .. now do stuff that only users in any of the roles listed are allowed to do

  // -- OR --

  // == Only do certain things if the username given is a member of any of the roles given ==
  if( $role->has_role('a_list, of_roles, allowed', 'username_currently_logged_in') ){
      // .. do stuff that only users in the given role(s) are allowed to do ..
  }


?>
```